# $n$-th root of a complex number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I am confused about the following problem. With $w=se^{i{\phi}}$, where $s\ge 0$ and $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$, solve the equation $z^n=w$ in $\mathbb{C}$ where $n$ is a natural number. How many solutions are there?

Now my approach is simply taking the $n$-th root which gives

$$z=\sqrt[n]{s}e^{\frac{i\varphi}{n}}$$

However, it seems that this problem is asking us to show the existance of the $n$-th root. Can I assume that the $n$-th root of a complex number already exists? Moreoover, would I be correct to say that there is only one solution which is given above?

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#nth_roots. Every non-zero complex number has $n$ (different) $n$-th roots.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471595/complex-nth-roots-of-a-complex-number.

Comment: This is an exercise in the book by Stein and Shakarchi, if anyone wonders.